# How to use group by in a tabular udf properly?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a creating a tabular UDF that accepts a start date and end date and then shows the commission earned by each employee_IDs in that period.
I was trying it here but was getting incorrect syntax near employeeId.

```
create Function CommissionByDate(@start_d date,@end_d date)
Returns table
As
Return
(
Select Employee_ID
  ,sum(dbo.OfferCommission(Offer_value, Offer_date)) as Commission 
from Campaign_Offer
where Acceptance_status = 'yes' And Offer_date >= @start_d And Offer_date <=   
@end_d group by Employee_ID
```

Comment: Looks ok to me...well except for that scalar function in the middle there. Syntactically though it seems to be fine. My comment about the scalar function is because they are notoriously poor from a performance standpoint. You do seem to have an extra opening parenthesis at the beginning of your select statement which should go away.

Comment: I feel so stupid...thanks man..I didnt even see the parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to close bracket after `GROUP BY Employee_ID`

```
CREATE FUNCTION CommissionByDate
(
    @start_d DATE
    , @end_d DATE
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT Employee_ID, sum(dbo.OfferCommission(Offer_value, Offer_date)) AS Commission
    FROM Campaign_Offer
    WHERE Acceptance_status = 'yes'
        AND Offer_date >= @start_d
        AND Offer_date <= @end_d
    GROUP BY Employee_ID
    )
```

This should work